# It is difficult to accept (it)

Tags: sentence-construction, personal-pronouns

I am speaking about a man who receives a piece of advice from a friend, but because the advice entails radical changes in his life he replies:

> Your advice is so demanding, it is difficult to accept!

Now, while I was typing this, my fingers couldn't stop there, but by instinct went on to type ***it*** at the end.

> Your advice is so demanding, it is difficult to accept it!

Are they both acceptable? If they are, is there additional information in the second variant?

Comment: Here's a (somewhat contrived) context where it really could make a difference to the ***meaning*** if you did or didn't include the pronoun at the end... *I'm not sure that "**supercalifragilisticexpialidocious**" is a useful word to teach to learners. It's hard to say [**it**]*. Without the pronoun, that last sentence would more naturally be interpreted as *I find it **difficult to decide** [whether it's a useful word or not].* But *with* the pronoun, it could only be interpreted as ***articulating that word** is difficult.*

Comment: You definitely nailed it now!

Comment: Not quite! I feel sure that there must be at least some contexts where ***almost all*** native speakers would include "it" in such constructions. And some ***other*** contexts where almost ***none*** of us would do so. In my example above, both versions are *possible* - they just mean different things. But there should be other contexts where only one version is idiomatically acceptable.

Comment: @FF: what I meant is that this is exactly what I intuitively thought that the difference would be in my example, too. So IT really fits my question. But certainly, the matter cannot be so easily done with...

Comment: Just so long as we're clear. *Your* example only has one meaning, with or without "it". It's a complete red herring to introduce the idea that if "it" isn't specified, you might be having difficulty accepting something other than "your advice". But with *my* example, even though it would be more *naturally* interpreted as ***difficult to decide*** without "it", the alternative ***difficult to pronounce*** parsing is at least *possible*.

Comment: I should have said in my last comment _...what I intuitively thought that, **by contrast**, the difference would be in my example, **just like you did**_. Sorry to confuse you there

Comment: It's a good question. I'm glad you asked [it].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contexts where *[**verb**]* is a *transitive* verb used in the construction...

> *It's [**adjective**] to [**verb**]*

...it's largely a stylistic choice whether to explicitly specify the "object" of the verb *(**it**)* at the end of the utterance. Thus...

> *I like this game. It's fun to play [**it**]*

...is *syntactically* valid with or without ***it*** at the end. But *idiomatically,* native speakers don't normally<sup>1</sup> include it.

---

Note that although we *don't* usually include ***it*** in such constructions, this is nothing to do with the fact that the utterance *starts* with a (completely unrelated) use of "existential" ***it*** (as in ***It**'s hot today!*, where ***it*** doesn't really reference anything at all; it's just an established construction). Usually, only non-native speakers notice and are bothered by such "repetition".

---

<sup>1</sup> I may be overstating the case here. Perhaps it's safer to say *Native speakers **often don't** include **"it"***. There are probably some "guiding principles" as regards where we're more (or *less*) likely to include it. But even if that's true, the fact that I myself am not consciously aware of any such principles suggests learners don't need to worry much about it either.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you. I am not sure how they call it in English but I would describe the first IT as an impersonal pronoun (without a referent as you say), whereas the second definitely replaces the advice. But am I in the wrong when I look at the first variant I gave and understand _(IT) The advice is difficult to accept?_

Comment: @fev the basic answer is that you are correct. However, if one left a longer pause where the comma is (in speech!), it would be ambiguous: again, the 'it' could either directly refer to the advice, or it could refer to the situation in general (similarly to "It's hard to believe that she did that.") I'm a little surprised by the downvotes on my answer, but opinions will always differ, I guess.

Comment: @legatrix: Per previous comment, I don't think there's any scope in OP's context for supposing that what's "difficult to accept" is anything other than "your advice". The alternative (it's difficult to accept *my life in general*) would have to be expressed differently.

Comment: Fair enough to both of you! I guess the main point is that you don't need to worry about the difference too much, as @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica said.

Comment: @FF: Am I in the wrong when I look at the first variant I gave and understand _(IT) The advice is difficult to accept_?

Comment: @fev: No, you're certainly ***not*** wrong when you say the first variant means *Your advice is difficult to accept*.  That is exactly the ***only*** meaning, regardless of whether or not ***it*** appears at the end of the utterance.

Comment: I usually leave off objects (of verbs or of prepositions) at the end of a sentence when they’ve been stated previously in the sentence or clear from context. But sometimes I don’t, and I don’t know why.

Comment: @StephenS: I backtracked from my original assertion that native speakers "usually" don't bother with that implied object pronoun (I reduced it to "often"). But it might be interesting to see if we can identify any ***specific*** contexts where it's either very likely or very *unlikely* that we would explicitly include it.

Answer (score -2):

They're largely the same, and both acceptable. However, I would suggest that the first has one reading only:

- Your advice is so demanding, it's difficult to accept [your advice]

whereas the second has two readings:

- Your advice is so demanding, it's difficult to accept [your advice]
- Your advice is so demanding, it's difficult to accept ['things' in general; i.e. the general current situation in which you are giving me advice]

So in the second, 'it' can have a slightly more general reading; however, the practical meaning is very similar.

By the way, I'm not sure if advice itself should really be called demanding. Perhaps the things that are advised would be demanding if one did them.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. What word would you use instead?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, perhaps someone else can comment. I would probably use a longer sentence or couple of sentence, something like "I appreciate your advice, but it would require me to change so much that I'm not sure I'm up to the challenge".

Comment: Hm, between friends I would say this is too explicative :) How about _Talk about some advice! It's so hard to accept (it)!_ Would that do?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see the presence or absence of terminating ***it*** as relevant to this semantic distinction. Once "your advice" has been mentioned, it's impossible for me to interpret ***difficult to accept*** as referencing anything *other* than that advice, with or without ***it***.

Comment: I see your point, and I note that nothing I wrote goes against your syntactic optionality explanation, but I maintain that there can be an objective 'it' without a specific syntactic antecedent, whose reference is determined pragmatically as the question under discussion. For me, this 'it' is a possible (and fairly standard) reading, which is why I gave it. This is the 'it' of "I just can't take it anymore."

Comment: @legatrix: I do not feel that the second IT can refer to anything else than the advice.If the speaker wanted to refer to something more general, the sentence would have looked something more like this: _Your advice is so demanding. It is difficult to accept (all) this._ As my original variant is formulated, I think it rules out the possibility you indicated.

Comment: That's up to you, no problem! Here's another example I just spoke to ensure it sounds right: "Your cheating and your lies, I can't just forget it!" This sounds fine to me, and would be the same *it* of situational reference (often followed by *all*). Note that strict syntactic reference would require *them" (which is of course also possible). But I won't keep defending this point. It's your choice, after all!

Comment: @legatrix: "Your cheating and your lies, I can't just forget it!" is a better example of your point. I accept that.

Comment: I think you're confusing the issue by bringing up *I just can't take it!* in this context. Admittedly, it's possible to tease out two alternative parsings for *Your advice is useless. I just can't take it!* (where "it" might be "your advice" OR it might be "my circumstances"). But that's a completely different verb, and a completely different construction (where it's syntactically invalid to simply discard that final *"**it**"*).

Comment: *Your cheating and your lies, I can't just forget it* is a *feasible* utterance for a native speaker, but it's syntactically highly suspect, and far less likely to occur in a *written* context.

Comment: Suspect if one regarded it as a single syntactic unit, yes---which I don't. Agree that far less likely to occur in written context.